# Angular2 simple gallery

Tags: angular

I want to do simple gallery in my angular2 project, something like this:

[enter link description here](https://designshack.net/tutorialexamples/lightbox-gallery/index.html)

I have tried with jquery lightbox and another plugins but it dosent works. Can somebody show me how to do simple gallery in steps?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply google it and can find something like this:

1. https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-image-gallery
2. https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/galleria

Documentation for these are also available in the same page.